# Enabling permalinks disables custom page template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, page-template

I have assigned a custom template on a page in wordpress, but it's not working anymore after I enable permalinks. Instead of the custom template, the "post-type-archive-portfolio" template is used.

This custom template is used to display all posts (custom type posts). I have checked my htaccess file, I tried to enable-disable permalinks again and again but none of these worked.

Here is the template file and the code tha creates the custom post type and taxonomy.

**Custom post type creation:**

```
/* Portfolio Custom Posts */
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', /* this can be seen at the URL as a parameter and a unique id for the custom post */
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio','textdomain_simple' ), /* The Label of the custom post */
                'singular_name' => __( "All Portfolio", 'textdomain_simple' ) /* The Label of the custom post */
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'), /* The slug of the custom post */
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ), /* enable basic for text editing */
        )
    );

/* Portfolio Taxonomies/Categories */
function portfolio_taxonomie() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio_category',
        array( 'portfolio' ),
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'with_front' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio Category', 'textdomain_topbest' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Porfolio Category', 'textdomain_topbest' )
            ),
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'portfolio' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_taxonomie', 0 );

function custom_post_type_tags( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_tags' );
```

**`Template file:`**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Portfolio Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

   <!-- Start main content -->
   <div class="container main-content clearfix">

       <div id="intro">
          <blockquote><?php the_field('intro_message'); ?></blockquote>
        </div>



        <div class="portfolio">

        <div class="sixteen columns">  
          <div class="title clearfix" id="options">
            <span>Filter:</span>
            <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
              <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Projects</a></li>
              <?php
                $terms = get_terms("portfolio_category");
                $count = count($terms);
                    if ( $count > 0 ){
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';

                }
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- End options -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div id="contain"> 

        <!-- =================================================== -->

        <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'portfolio');
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );                  
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                $term_links = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_links[] = $term->slug;
                    }                   
                $the_term = join( " ", $term_links );
                $the_term_separated = join( ", ", $term_links );
        ?>

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ){ ?>
        <!-- Start Portfolio Item -->
          <div class="one-third column item element-3 <?php echo $the_term; ?>" data-categories="<?php echo $the_term; ?>">
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-thumb'); ?>
              </a>
              <div class="info">
                <h3><?php echo vp_metabox('portfolio_option.list_title'); ?>.</h3> 
                <a class="more" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Find out more »</a>  
              </div>            
          </div>
          <!-- End Portfolio Item -->
          <?php } ?>

         <?php endif; ?> 
         <?php wp_reset_query(); endforeach; ?>

          <!-- =================================================== -->

        </div><!-- End contain-->

        </div><!-- End portfolio -->

   </div><!-- <<< End Container >>> -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Do you have any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of

```
'has_archive' => true
```

which instruct wordpress to look for an archive template for the CPT. If you have a page with the same slug (portfolio) it will never get to display it as everything gets priority over pages.